# Oracle SQL query to return 1 or 0 based on if value exists

Tags: sql, oracle

I have 2 table Question and Answer tables.
Question table has

```
ID Question_Text
1  Question1
2  Question2
3  Question3
```

Answer table

```
Question_ID Answer_text Answered_by
1           Ans1        User1
1           Ans2        User2
1           Ans3        User3
2           Ans4        User1
```

I need to find out which all questions were answered already?
Desired outcome

```
ID Question_Text Answered
1  Question1     true/1
2  Question2     true/1
3  Question3     false/0
```

I have written the below query to find whether the question is answered by using EXISTS. I need answered value true/false and also want to fine tune this query so that it checks for first occurrence in answer table and get the value as true/false, instead of running through the thousands of value in answer table.

```
SELECT * 
FROM QUESTIONS A 
WHERE  EXISTS (SELECT * 
               FROM ANSWERS B 
               WHERE A.QUESTION_ID = B.QUESTION_ID);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

A simple `LEFT JOIN` will do:

```
SELECT  Q.*, 
        CASE WHEN A.Question_ID IS NULL THEN 0 ELSE 1 END Answered
FROM Question Q
LEFT JOIN ( SELECT DISTINCT Question_ID
            FROM Answer) A
    ON Q.ID = A.Question_ID;
```

Comment: Was about to answer the same :)

Comment: The second row (definition of "Answered") can also be written as `NVL2(A.Question_ID, 1, 0)` - not a different solution, just a different way to write it.

Comment: @mathguy that assumes that the question is for Oracle, but it's also tagged with SQL Server, so I chose a way that works in both

Comment: @Lamak thanks it works. Solution in 2 minutes, appreciated.

Comment: @Lamak - not sure how it was tagged before it was edited, but it says **Oracle SQL** right in the title - I don't know how that can be confusing.

Comment: @mathguy as I said, it was tagged with both SQL Server an Oracle, not sure how my comment about it was confusing.

Comment: I didn't mean your comment was confusing. I meant, the original post wasn't confusing - even if tagged for both (which happens often on SO), the title didn't leave room for confusion. Not a big deal though, there is no requirement to use NVL2() - your solution is perfectly fine without it.

Comment: @mathguy I undersood your comment, and the passive agressive "I don't know how that can be confusing" too, that's why I add that to my comment too. Anyway, I know what the title said, but since the answers are for the community, and when you search SO you'll most likely search for tags, I decided to give an answer that worked with both tags

Answer (score 0):

Try:
`SELECT
  Q.*,
  CASE
    WHEN EXISTS
      ( SELECT *
        FROM ANSWERS A
        WHERE A."Question_ID" = Q.ID
      ) THEN 'true/1'
    ELSE 'false/0'
  END Answered
FROM QUESTIONS Q
ORDER BY ID`
This has the advantage of not having to `DISTINCT` ANSWERS first. If ANSWERS is big and has an index on Question_ID it may be faster, especially for selected questions.  It's still not a proper semi-join solution. The query optimiser could surprise with both this and the @Lamak solution using real data.